# Trouble running a BLASTN parsing program

Tags: python

I want to write a program that will open a BLASTN output file parse out specific information, and produce formatted output that will be written to STDOUT.
Program must open the input file parsing and storing both the query sequence ID.

```
Query ID: IREALLYLIKEPYTHON Query Length: 15
```

For just the first ten hits, parse out only the accession (located between the first set of pipe symbols, | | ), length and score. For each of these hits, these three fields should then be written to STDOUT.

```
Alignment #1: Accession = ref|XM_005094338.1| (Length = 2377, Score = 1098)
```

Here is my attempt, I don't know what I am doing wrong. When I try running the program using the following prompt in shell:
$ python script.py blast.file
but nothing gets printed.

Here is my code:

```
import argparse
import os
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--input_file', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output_file', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    Query_ID = None
    Query_length = None
    output_file = open(args.blastp_file, "w")
    output_file.write("The file will have parsed information based on   your query.")
    for line in open(args.input_file, 'r'):
        column = line.split("\t")
        Query_Id = column[0];
        m = re.search("Score =(\d+)", line)
    blastn_file = input_file.read()
    fout = sys.stdout
    output_file.close()
    if__name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    for score
```

Comment: Are you using the indentation as shown?

Comment: What do expect to happen? There is no `print` in the shown code.

Comment: Where would I put the print? Also, the query ID and alignment are example outputs. That is what my output should look like.

Comment: You write *"$ python script.py blast.file but nothing gets printed."*. Do you man your output file is empty?

Comment: My output file is not empty.